# Python NoneType error when posting a database row

Tags: python, web2py

I am getting a NoneType attribute error when trying to create a page on Web2Py. I am trying to load the 'show' page and I get a NoneType error for my Product_Name attribute.

Here is the database I have created:

```
db.define_table('products',
            Field('Product_Name',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('Product_Description',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('Product_Review',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()))
```

Here is my controller:

```
    def index():
    form = SQLFORM(db.products).process()
    rows = db(db.products).select()
    return locals()

def show():
    post = db.products(2)
    return locals()
```

Here is the page I am trying to run (show):

```
    {{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>{{=post.Product_Name}}</h2>

<p>Hellooooo
    {{=post.Product_Description}}
    {{=post.Product_Review}}
</p>
```

Here is a page related to my show page:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

## Current Products

```
<table class="table">
    {{for row in rows:}}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{=URL('show',args=row.id)}}">{{=row.Product_Name}}</a></td>          
    </tr>
    {{pass}}
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give the actual traceback for the exception? `NoneType` is not an error (it's `type(None)`), but there are plenty of errors that could refer to it (probably `AttributeError`s most of the time, but it could be something else). I don't speak `web2py` so I can't help directly, but I'd guess you're getting `None` back from your database when the input doesn't match anything you have in the DB.

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>('NoneType' object has no attribute 'products')

Comment: That pretty clearly suggests that `db` is `None`.

Comment: The database is definitely there, I am just not relating the record to the correct increment on "show", I can happily return the database results into a table on the index page. But when creating a hyperlink from the table row leading to the show page, the error appears.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\applications\App3\views\default/show.html", line 75, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.products(2)` returns the record from the `db.products` table whose `id` is 2. If no such record has yet been created (which appears to be your case), then it will instead return `None`. In the view, when you then have `post.Product_Name`, that is equivalent to `None.Product_name`, which raises the `NoneType` error you are seeing.

You probably want some logic either in the `show()` controller function or its associated view to handle the case where the requested product `id` does not exist (either redirect or show a special message in the view).

Also, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42497793/440323), because the links on the "index" page have URLs like `URL('show', args=row.id)` (with the `db.products` record ID as the first URL arg), you should retrieve the requested record in the `show` controller via:

```
post = db.products(request.args(0, cast=int))
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, when I change it to "post = db.products(0)" to get the very first record I still get the NoneType exception attribute error, but when changing it to "post = db.products(1) " I get an "<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>()" error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Database record IDs typically start at 1 (and never at 0), so `db.products(1)` would be the first record. In `db.sometable(n)`, the `n` is not a Python list index (which would start at 0), but a database record ID (i.e., the value stored in the primary key `id` column).

Comment: If you are still getting at `AttributeError` after correctly retrieving a record, most likely that means you have misspelled a field name in your view, though there could be some completely unrelated `AttributeError`. It's impossible to say without seeing the full traceback and all the relevant code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\applications\App3\views\default/show.html", line 75, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

Comment: Code listing:


    def __getattr__(self, k):
        try:
            return self.__getitem__(k)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError


    def __copy__(self):
        return Row(self)

Comment: You'll have to check your code. In the `show.html` view, you must be accessing a field name that is either misspelled or is not actually in the `db.products` model definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by post being None, then the view tries to access post.Product_Description and post.Product_Review, and then you get an AttributeError.

Probably you want to change

```
post = db.products(2)
```

to

```
post = db.products(request.args(0, cast=int))
```

This would make it coherent with the links you're making in index.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this then gives me a "<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>()" error.

Comment: @NicholasNicolaou Can you show me the full stack trace? Do you have migrations turned on?  .

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\applications\App3\views\default/show.html", line 75, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 90, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError

Sorry I am not sure if I have migrations turned on or not.

Comment: @NicholasNicolaou in your application's private folder check appconfig.ini make sure migrate is set to true